# Why do I get different output from the same commands? (redirect and piping)

Tags: command-line, redirect, pipe

So I'm learning to use the CLI and I'm playing around with redirecting and piping and then I get different output from executing the same commands.

Basically I'm listing all executables from /bin/ and /usr/bin/ in a .txt file, and afterwards changing the same .txt file to only list the duplicate entries. First time I executed the 2 commands it didn't work, but the second time it worked. I repeated the 2 commands a couple of more times and sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Here's a snippet from my terminal:

```
username@computer:~/playground$ ls /bin/ /usr/bin/ > ls_bin_usr-bin.txt 
username@computer:~/playground$ cat ls_bin_usr-bin.txt | sort | uniq -d | tee ls_bin_usr-bin.txt | wc -l
0
username@computer:~/playground$ ls /bin/ /usr/bin/ > ls_bin_usr-bin.txt 
username@computer:~/playground$ ls -l
total 20
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 19816 Feb  9 17:27 ls_bin_usr-bin.txt
username@computer:~/playground$ cat ls_bin_usr-bin.txt | sort | uniq -d | tee ls_bin_usr-bin.txt | wc -l
12
username@computer:~/playground$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 92 Feb  9 17:27 ls_bin_usr-bin.txt
```

How come it doesn't behave in the same way every time?

I'm on Xubuntu 18.04 btw

Comment: In case you don't understand what's going on in your case: `cat ls_bin_usr-bin.txt` _reads_ the file and `tee ls_bin_usr-bin.txt` _writes_ the very same file. As explained in the other question, it is not predictable "who comes first" when both commands are run in a pipe `|`.

Comment: Yea it all makes sense to me after reading the other question :-) Guess I just didn't know what to search for. Thanks anyway, though.

Comment: Yeah this is one of those cases where the appropriate search terms ("truncate", "pipe", "race condition") aren't obvious until you know the answer ;)